# how to change text dynamically with raphael

Tags: text, raphael

Ok, this is basically what I'm doing right now. I create the raphael text object. I use a click event to open a dialog box. Then I make the changes to the text in the dialog box. This isn't how I wish to implement this though. I want my implementation to be somewhat similar to the way text is created in MS Paint where the user can click on the text object and change the text as they're typing. Does anybody know how to implement this using a raphael text object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create a `<textarea>` when the user starts editing the text. Fill it with the current text and place it over the text object. Then, when it loses focus (`onblur`), remove the text area and copy the text back into the text object.

If you really want to edit the text "in place" in the text object, then you can let the user type in a hidden text field. But in this case you'll have to implement all the cursor and selection logic yourself. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8QZH/) (which only allows using the right and left arrows to move the cursor, with shift to select text so that you can copy and paste).

Alternately, I don't know if [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) works for SVG content, but that would be a very simple solution if it did work.